# Delete blank rows in new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub vova()

Dim S_path As String
Dim S_name1  As String, S_nameW1 As String
S_path = "S:\Ãîëîâíèé Áàíê\Öåíòð óïðàâë³ííÿ ãîò³âêîþ\"
S_path = Trim(S_path) + Trim(Worksheets("1").Range("D6").Value) + ".xlsx"
 
 
Range("A1:N27").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
S_nameW1 = ActiveWorkbook.name
S_name1 = ActiveSheet.name


Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 2
Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 35
Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 13
Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 15
Columns("N:N").ColumnWidth = 15

Application.CutCopyMode = False

With S_name1
For i = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row To 9 Step -1

If .Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
 .Rows(i & ":" & i).Delete
End If

Next

End With

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=S_path, FileFormat:= _
xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

help solve the problem need macro to delete rows that are not field in range and create new workbook with field raws and columns.  Getting this error (in column B there are drop down lists) and formulas in columns C,D,E

[image]

[image]

created workbook should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the name of the sheet to S_name1

Change

```
With S_name1
```

to

```
With WorkBooks(S_NameW1).WorkSheets(S_name1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Volodymyr, you used a string variable with `With` keyword. You should use an object variable there.

```
...
Dim S_name1 as Worksheet
...
Set S_name1 = ActiveSheet
...
```